# Graph API - Post comment seems Ok but no new comment added

Tags: android, facebook

I have just used the Graph API some days ago and struggling with the comments.
I can retrieve all the comment using the link:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://example.com/my_post_here
```

It returns all the comments as expected. cool for now. :)

Then I try to post a comment to that post using the facebook sdk (call directlt to the link does not work. :( )

The code to post comment (after logging with publish_actions permission granted)

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", comment);
String grapPath = "http://example.com/my_post_here/comments";
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                graphLink,
                bundle,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        Log.e(TAG, "Graph resp:" +     response.getRawResponse());
                    }
                }
).executeAsync();
```

I can see the onCompleted callback get called and the raw response looks like this:

```
{"id":"738551662920009","url":"http://example.com/my_post_here/comments"}
```

At first I think the comment is posted succesfully but It does not. I dont see any my new comments on my post, that makes me confuse what the above Graph response mean. Did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Comment: You can not make comments on external Open Graph objects via API. Only the Comments plugin allows this.

Comment: @CBroe: Really? From the document (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/comment), at the Publish section, they said "You can publish comments by using the /comments edge when it is present on a node.". Are they updated the Graph API?. If yes, then I think they must document that somewhere.

Comment: And the node you have here is the [URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/url) node – and it doesn’t mention a `/comments` edge in that document.

Comment: oh, thanks for the link. Do you have any idea for implementation the facebook comment for Android?. thanks.

Comment: The Comments plugin is available for web only.

Comment: Yes, I know, I try to use the facebook comment box inside a webview but it seems not a good approach for a native look.